# RabbitMQ instead of WebHooks

Tags: rabbitmq, webhooks

We have a project which provides API for a number of clients who are approved by us (we sign paper contracts with them). Our clients want to get updates from us about their resources (all clients are independent). Currently, we consider WebHooks and RabbitMQ to stream events. RabbitMQ sounds exotic since it will be used by external clients (yeah, we approve them, but we don't control them). If we go with WebHooks, we need to re-implement lots of features which we get for free from RabbitMQ.

Features we need to implement in case of WebHooks:

- authentication and subscription (some clients have a few independent apps, so they need a way to tell us where their apps are)
- signed requests (they need to be sure requests come from us)
- a retry mechanism (we don't have to deal with it if we choose RabbitMQ)
- a mechanism to guarantee the order of events (it is even more fun considering the retry mechanism. Again we don't need this if we choose RabbitMQ)
- kind of topics, so they only get what they need

Have you heard about any experience of using RabbitMQ in place of WebHooks? Does it sound too crazy?

Comment: Provide a solid NON-RABBIT/NON-AMQP interface with clients. Use RabbitMQ *internally*, where such message queue design such make sense (RabbitMQ is good in many cases, but there are better queue alternatives in certain domains). That is, RabbitMQ is an *implementation detail* like SQL Server .. and one generally doesn't allow clients to connect directly to their SQL instances :}

Comment: And yes, I *do* have experience backing my above "rule": as *even 'internally, within an organization'* there can easily far too much domain / implementation bleed and lack of definition and control due to using RabbitMQ instead of establishing better boundaries. Allowing external client access to RabbitMQ only compounds this problem and makes it more difficult to secure access (ie. how to 'punch' the network, manage client access/permissions, provide auditing?).

Comment: (Maybe 'WebHooks' can provide the interface with clients and leverage RabbitMQ internally? *shrug*)

Comment: One thing you may consider: With subscriptions, the _subscriber_ decides to subscribe and the subscriber connects to the server. It is NAT/firewall friendly and doesn't require reconfiguration on the server side. With webhooks, you have to configure the subscriber in the server and the server connects to the client. Which doesn't work if the subscriber is behind a firewall  (aren't most?). I really hate webhooks! :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to send events through direclty RabbitMQ, you will face the following challenges:

1. You have to send the same event to different queues in order for your clients only to receive their own events. E.x.: `client1.invoice.paid`, `client2.invoice.paid`
2. You have to create an account in RabbitMq for each client, it will create the challenges of user management.
3. Security. Your Rabbitmq service port is going to be open to the public.

In order to avoid those challenges, you should implement a webhook dispatch service with RabbitMq. 
How does it work?

1. Send your event from the main app to RabbitMQ.
2. Webhook service receives the event and sends it to the URL accordingly.

Check this URL to get an idea of how to design webhook service: 
 https://www.slideshare.net/jbliao/how-to-design-reliable-and-scalable-webhooks-with-rabbitmq